# Having trouble finding negative values

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, graphing-functions, maxima-minima

I was messing around with a function but cannot seem to get the intervals where it assumes negative values right.

Let $f(x)=3x^\frac{2}{3}-x$. Find the relative extrema of $f(x)$ in $[-1;27]$.

What I did was try to get the intervals where its first derivative assumes positive and negative values ($f'(x)>0$ and $f'(x)<0$ respectively), roots ($f'(x)=0$) and other critical points ($f'(x)$ Does Not Exist).
I got $x<8 \Rightarrow f'(x)>0$ and $ x > 8 \Rightarrow f'(x)<0$. $x=8$ is obvs. a maximum and $x=0 \Rightarrow \nexists f'(0)$.
I'm having trouble showing that $f'(x)$ assumes negative values in the interval $[-1; 0)$. Any way I can get that out of an equation?

Comment: $f'(x)=2x^{-1/3}-1$. For $x<0,x^{-1/3}<0$ giving $f'(x)<0$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What is $x^{2/3}$ when $x$ is negative?